# How do I reset the value passed to the class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, conditional-statements

I have a class Vector.

```
    Vector::Vector(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (x > 100 || y > 100 || z > 100)
        {
            std::cout<<"the value should not be higher than 100"<<std::endl;
            this->x = 0; this->y = 0; this->z = 0; // This entry does not work
        }
    }

int main()
{
   Vector direction = Vector(100, 50, 10); // x has 100;
   std::cout << direction; // output 0, 0, 0
   return 0;
}
```

How do I make it so that if one of the 3 arguments has a value higher than 100, then it will be reset and everyone will have 0 0 0

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Do you know how to use constructors' initialization sections? If you are unfamiliar with this terminology, you will find more information in your C++ textbook. If you do, is there anything in the textbook's explanation that's unclear to you? Before you can "reset" anything in a class, your constructor must initialize the class members, first, and the shown code does not initializate any class members. All it does is declare the constructor's parameters.

Comment: None of the passed in values is greater than 100 in your example.

Comment: I forgot in the example >=

Comment: You also need to ensure the constructor initialises the members if none of the arguments are greater than 100.   At present, your code ONLY sets values to zero if any argument is more than 100, but leaves them uninitialised otherwise

Comment: can I get an example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you do not have an overloaded operator to do `cout<<direction`;.
Furthermore, in your constructor you are checking for `>100` not `>=100` which is why you are not getting your output

here is the working code-

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class Vector
{
    int x, y, z;

public:
    Vector(int, int, int);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Vector &);
};
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Vector &obj)
{
    return os << obj.x << " " << obj.y << " " << obj.z;
}
Vector::Vector(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (x >= 100 || y >= 100 || z >= 100)
    {
        std::cout << "the value should not be higher than 100" << std::endl;
        this->x = 0;
        this->y = 0;
        this->z = 0; // This entry does not work
    }
    else
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Vector direction = Vector(100, 50, 10); // x has 100;
    std::cout << direction;                 // output 0, 0, 0
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the arguments aren't valid, often the appropriate response is to throw an exception:

```
Vector::Vector(int x1, int y1, int z1)
    : x(x1), y(y1), z(z1)
{
if (x1 >= 100 || y1 >= 100 || z1 >= 100)
    throw std::invalid_argument("Input argument too large");
}
```

that way you don't end up with objects with bad values.